# Can mule-restlet map a URL pattern to a specific method?

Tags: playframework, restlet, mule

To translate an incoming http request to the specific method in [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/routese) web framework is straight forward, which look like as follows:

```
GET    /users/{userId}  UserController.getUser   
POST   /users           UserController.addUser
PUT    /users           UserController.updateUser
DELETE /users/{userId}  UserController.deleteUser
```

But I find it hard to do this in Mule-Restlet.

```
<model name="userModel">
    <service name="userService">
        <inbound>
            <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63080"/>
        </inbound>
        <outbound>
            <filtering-router>
                <outbound-endpoint address="vm://userController"/>
                <or>
                    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users/{userId}" verbs="GET"/>
                    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users" verbs="POST"/>
                    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users" verbs="PUT"/>
                    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users/{userId}" verbs="DELETE"/>
                </or>
            </filtering-router>
        </outbound>
    </service>
    <service name="userController">
        <inbound>
            <inbound-endpoint address="vm://userController"/>
        </inbound>
        <!-- **TODO: How to implement UserController** -->
        <component class="com.ggd543.mulerestletdemo.user.UserController"/>
    </service>
</model>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Restlet Transport doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/RESTLET/User%27s+Guide#User%27sGuide-URITemplateRouting), you should be able to shorten your routing map to:

```
<or-filter>
    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users" verbs="POST PUT"/>
    <restlet:uri-template-filter pattern="/users/{userId}" verbs="GET DELETE"/>
</or-filter>
```

Then to develop your UserController resource, refer to the [Restlet's user guide](http://wiki.restlet.org/books/) that is relevant to the version in use by the transport.

Comment: David Dossot, Could you provide your contact info , I have lots of question to ask you

Comment: What about asking these questions in here, for the benefit of others?

Comment: Both MuleSoft forums/mailing lists and StackOverflow Mule tags are well followed and very responsive.